# CTRL+Z No longer undoing, switching between Solid and Textured display modes

Tags: shortcut

CTRL + Z in blender no longer undoes, and instead switches between Textured and Solid display modes for geometry in 3d mode. Any idea how I might have caused this to happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might have changed your **keyboard layout** to another language. German to English would result in such a behaviour, since it switches the Z and Y key.

Answer (score 0):

Go to File->User preferences->Input Tab->Search for "Undo" and assign the shortcut to ctrl+Z then press the `Save User settings` button on the bottom